# Accidentally used mv in shell script and moved files. Where do shell scripts run by default on mac?

Tags: python, macos, shell

I accidentally created and ran *this shell script*

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir container
mv * container
```

This moved a bunch of files to the container directory where the shell script was, but it also moved *a bunch of files I didn't intend to move.*

```
All Mail            
backup
HaxeFlixelProject       
chaos
Installer Log File      
chaos.pyc
Network 
cores
Python
installer.failurerequests
Resources
modules
User Guides And Information opt
User Information        test.sh
Volumes
```

I intended to move only *the files* that were in the shell script's directory

```
test1.txt
test2.txt
test3.txt
```

I expected my shell script to run in the *folder that the shell script resides*.

```
Desktop/test/1/
```

Where do shell scripts run by default?

Comment: `but it also moved a bunch of files I didn't intend to move.` that sounds unlikely(not countering what you said though). usually `mv` should abort with exit status of `1`  with this message `cannot move 'container' to a subdirectory of itself, 'container/container'`. Also the `*` should not copy hidden files.

Comment: How did your shell script exist in a directory that had not been created yet?

Comment: correction: I had the wrong path. My shell script resides in Desktop/test/1

Comment: I see, second question — which files or directories was it that you were intending to move into `container`?

Comment: The files that were in Desktop/test/1 (test1.txt, test2.txt, test3.txt)

Answer (score 1):

Shell scripts inherit their working directory from the process that launches them. If you run one from an interactive shell, it'll be whatever directory you were in when you ran it. It has nothing to do with the directory the script is in. I'd use the Finder to search for the "container" directory.

From the list of moved files and directories you list, I'd guess it was at the root directory, i.e. the top level of your startup disk, aka "/".

Answer (score 0):

Just run

```
find / -type d -name container 2>/dev/null
```

and find it.

## EDIT

As `container` has no path in your script, the only possibility is that the files moved were in container's parent.

Comment: Is this to find the container directory? I already know where this is. I don't know where the files that got copied into it came from.

Comment: These files didn't come from the directory where that bash script is. I don't know where they came from

Comment: the path to container is /Desktop/test/1/container
I created test and 1 immediately before container